# Google Big Query SQL TOP/Max/Order by

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-order-by

Here is my query that works:

> SELECT a_name, w_name, page_url, SUM(IF(result = 'WIN', 1, 0)) as Impressions,
>
> from TABLE_DATE_RANGE(v3_data.v3_,TIMESTAMP('2015-08-05'),TIMESTAMP('2015-08-07'))
>
> WHERE server ="server1" and w_id IN (1096, 1105, 1136,1153,1189,1209)
>
> GROUP EACH BY 1,2,3
>
> ORDER BY Impressions DESC
>
> limit 1000000

Now my issue is I dont want to use a limit.

What I would like to do is choose the top 1000 results from each w_id, ordered by the impressions.

There are multiple w_ids and this query will be extended to multiple servers too.

originally I thought id try:

> select top 1000 * from [code above] group by 1,2,3

but top doesnt work like that in big query and if I did that it wouldnt choose the top 1000 for each w_id it would do it over the whole set, so I could get none of the results for w_id 1209 if they are all relatively small.

I hope this is enough information, I've been given a lot of stick on here for being to vague, but im trying to give as much detail and be as logical as I can.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery supports `ROW_NUMBER()` which is the function you need to do this easily.

You do need to include `w_id` in the `group by`, but I think the following should do what you want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT a_name, w_name, page_url,
             SUM(IF(result = 'WIN', 1, 0)) as Impressions,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY w_id
                                ORDER BY SUM(IF(result = 'WIN', 1, 0)) DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      from TABLE_DATE_RANGE(v3_data.v3_, TIMESTAMP('2015-08-05'), TIMESTAMP('2015-08-07'))
      WHERE server = 'server1' and w_id IN (1096, 1105, 1136, 1153, 1189, 1209)
      GROUP EACH BY 1, 2, 3, w_id
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 1000;
```

If BigQuery doesn't support `row_number()` in an aggregation, you might need an additional layer of aggregation.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I still get Error: Resources exceeded during query execution - also I changes the order by bit to Impresions as it was already defined and they cant order by a SUM

Comment: I also removed the t.* at the start and t at the end, can you explain why that was put in (I tried with both) as I've never seen that done

Comment: @Oliver . . . the `t` is just a table alias, required by some databases and often a good idea.